# Why my input's value get cleared when I append a child?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

I'm having trouble when I append an element inside a `div` and is that all the values from my inputs (including selected options) get cleared as is shown here:

[image: problem]

As you can see when I click the button "Añadir tecla", the text from the textbox and the selected option "Shift" goes back to default option that is "Flechas de movimiento".

Why this happens and how can I avoid it?

My code is the next:

```
var controls = [{value: "flechas", text: "Flechas de movimiento"}, {value: "letras", text: "Letras (WASD)"}, {value: "enter", text: "Enter"}, {value: "control", text: "Ctrl"}, {value: "alt", text: "Alt"}, {value: "espacio", text: "Espacio"}, {value: "der", text: "Click derecho"}, {value: "izq", text: "Click izquierdo"}, {value: "mover", text: "Mover el ratón"}, {value: "shift", text: "Shift"}, {value: "customkey", text: "Especificar tecla"}];

function addControl(e) 
{
    e.appendChild(getControlSelect());
}

function getControlSelect() 
{
    var select = document.createElement('select'),
        option,
        i = 0,
        il = controls.length,
        html = document.createElement('div'),
        text = document.createElement('input'),
        delbtn = document.createElement('input');

    text.type = "text";

    delbtn.type = "button";
    delbtn.value = "-";

    for (; i < il; ++i)
    {
        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value', controls[i].value);
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(controls[i].text));
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
    html.innerHTML += "<b>Tecla</b><br>";
    html.appendChild(select);
    html.innerHTML += "<br><b>Acción</b><br>";
    html.appendChild(text);
    html.appendChild(delbtn);

    return html;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Añadir tecla" onclick="addControl(this.parentNode)" />
</div>
```

As you can see, when I click "Añadir tecla" I call addControl function with the parentNode as unique parameter (this will used later for append the child inside it).

So, I don't know where is the problem, I think everything is correct, but It need something to avoid the values get cleared.

**EDIT:** The code I shared hasn't problems, but my complete code has here:

```js
var controls = [{value: "flechas", text: "Flechas de movimiento"}, {value: "letras", text: "Letras (WASD)"}, {value: "enter", text: "Enter"}, {value: "control", text: "Ctrl"}, {value: "alt", text: "Alt"}, {value: "espacio", text: "Espacio"}, {value: "der", text: "Click derecho"}, {value: "izq", text: "Click izquierdo"}, {value: "mover", text: "Mover el ratón"}, {value: "shift", text: "Shift"}, {value: "customkey", text: "Especificar tecla"}],
 skippedIndexes = [],
 sep = "<div class='sep' id='firstsep' style='width: 200px;'></div>",
 oldIndex = 0;//,
 //sInd = 0;

function addControl(e) 
{

 if(e.lastChild.className != "sep") e.innerHTML += sep;
 e.appendChild(getControlSelect());
 e.innerHTML += sep.replace(" id='firstsep'", "");
}

function onSelectChange(e) 
{
 //Modify the array
 //a = e.associatedInput

 //console.log(e.dataset.i);

 /*var newIndex;

 newIndex = e.selectedIndex;

 if(skippedIndexes.length > 0 && skippedIndexes.indexOf(oldIndex) > -1) skippedIndexes.splice(skippedIndexes.indexOf(oldIndex), 1); //Delete oldIndex

 if(skippedIndexes.length > 0 && skippedIndexes.indexOf(newIndex) == -1) skippedIndexes.push(newIndex);

 oldIndex = newIndex;*/

 //Change associated



}

function deleteFirstSep() 
{
 if(!document.getElementById("firstsep").nextSibling) document.getElementById("firstsep").remove();
}

function getControlSelect() 
{
 var select = document.createElement('select'),
     option,
     i = 0,
     il = controls.length,
     html = document.createElement('div'),
     text = document.createElement('input'),
     delbtn = document.createElement('input'),
     ascinpt = document.createElement('input'),
     html1 = document.createElement('div');

 html1.style.display = "inline-block";

 text.type = "text";
 text.name = "accion[]";
 text.style.width = "158px";

 delbtn.type = "button";
 delbtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'var e = this.parentNode;e.nextSibling.remove();e.remove();deleteFirstSep();');
 delbtn.value = "-";
 delbtn.style.padding = "0 5px";
 delbtn.style.marginLeft = "5px";
 delbtn.style.position = "relative";
 delbtn.style.top = "-20px";
 delbtn.style.left = "2px";

 ascinpt.name = "tecla[]";
 ascinpt.type = "hidden";

 select.id = "htmlkey";
 select.dataset.associatedInput = ascinpt;
 //select.dataset.i = sInd;
 //sInd++;
 select.setAttribute("onchange", "onSelectChange(this)");

 for (; i < il; ++i)
  if(skippedIndexes.indexOf(i) == -1) 
  {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.setAttribute('value', controls[i].value);
      option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(controls[i].text));
      select.appendChild(option);
  }
 html1.innerHTML += "<b>Tecla</b><br>";
 html1.appendChild(select);
 html1.innerHTML += "<br><b>Acción</b><br>";
 html1.appendChild(text);
 html.appendChild(html1);
 html.appendChild(delbtn);

 return html;
}
```

```css
.sep {
  border-top: 4px dashed #A4A4A4;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Añadir tecla" onclick="addControl(this.parentNode)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your code runs perfectly for me, no inputs lose their values when I click the button. Are you sure there's not some other javascript event firing that could be effecting this?

Comment: Ok. I forget to say that I have `select.setAttribute("onchange", "onSelectChange(this)");`. So, I call an empty function when I change the value, but, deleting this code line the same thing happens. Maybe is the browser? I'm using Chrome 46.

Comment: It works fine for me as well.

Comment: have you tried refreshing your browser or clearing the cache? You could be serving up cached content that is still loading the code you deleted.

Comment: I will try using JSFiddle.

Comment: I couldn't get it to run in JSFiddle, but here it is in CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RroRZv

Comment: The same happened to me using JSFiddle. :( Ok. I tested it and using the code I shared no problem occurs. But with my complete code troubles start. There is the complete code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgNbWE

Comment: Your codepen is completely fine!

Comment: It happens because you are rewriting the html of the container element. This way, live properties get lost. You should create an element in memory and append that, instead of rewriting the actual html property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you overwrite the HTML code

```
element.innerHTML += newHTML;
```

This gets rid of the state of the current elements, including event listeners, input values, checkedness, etc.

Instead, you should use `appendChild` or `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```
element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHTML);
```

```js
var controls = [{value: "flechas", text: "Flechas de movimiento"}, {value: "letras", text: "Letras (WASD)"}, {value: "enter", text: "Enter"}, {value: "control", text: "Ctrl"}, {value: "alt", text: "Alt"}, {value: "espacio", text: "Espacio"}, {value: "der", text: "Click derecho"}, {value: "izq", text: "Click izquierdo"}, {value: "mover", text: "Mover el ratón"}, {value: "shift", text: "Shift"}, {value: "customkey", text: "Especificar tecla"}],
  skippedIndexes = [],
  sep = "<div class='sep' id='firstsep' style='width: 200px;'></div>",
  oldIndex = 0; //,
//sInd = 0;

function addControl(e) {

  if (e.lastChild.className != "sep") e.innerHTML += sep;
  e.appendChild(getControlSelect());
  e.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', sep.replace(" id='firstsep'", ""));
}

function onSelectChange(e) {}

function deleteFirstSep() {
  if (!document.getElementById("firstsep").nextSibling) document.getElementById("firstsep").remove();
}

function getControlSelect() {
  var select = document.createElement('select'),
    option,
    i = 0,
    il = controls.length,
    html = document.createElement('div'),
    text = document.createElement('input'),
    delbtn = document.createElement('input'),
    ascinpt = document.createElement('input'),
    html1 = document.createElement('div');

  html1.style.display = "inline-block";

  text.type = "text";
  text.name = "accion[]";
  text.style.width = "158px";

  delbtn.type = "button";
  delbtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'var e = this.parentNode;e.nextSibling.remove();e.remove();deleteFirstSep();');
  delbtn.value = "-";
  delbtn.style.padding = "0 5px";
  delbtn.style.marginLeft = "5px";
  delbtn.style.position = "relative";
  delbtn.style.top = "-20px";
  delbtn.style.left = "2px";

  ascinpt.name = "tecla[]";
  ascinpt.type = "hidden";

  select.id = "htmlkey";
  select.dataset.associatedInput = ascinpt;
  //select.dataset.i = sInd;
  //sInd++;
  select.setAttribute("onchange", "onSelectChange(this)");
  for (; i < il; ++i)
    if (skippedIndexes.indexOf(i) == -1) {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.setAttribute('value', controls[i].value);
      option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(controls[i].text));
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
  html1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<b>Tecla</b><br>");
  html1.appendChild(select);
  html1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<br><b>Acción</b><br>");
  html1.appendChild(text);
  html.appendChild(html1);

  html.appendChild(delbtn);
  return html;
}
```

```css
.sep {
  border-top: 4px dashed #A4A4A4;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Añadir tecla" onclick="addControl(this.parentNode)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this advice! Can you give some more tips for improve my code organisation?

Comment: @Ikillnukes Instead of rebuilding the new control from scratch, consider cloning the existing one with `cloneNode`. Avoid inline styles, add a class instead and define them in a stylesheet. Avoid event handler content attributes which require global functions, use event handler IDL attributes or event listeners. You can post your code in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get more advices.